# Foursquare Java API seems to have wrong argument type for "checkinsAdd()" api call

Tags: java, android, api, foursquare

I was using the FS Java api 1.0.2 and I see that the 6th argument in `checkinsAdd()` is "ll-(latitude-longitude)"...
It expects a double value but I think it should be a string as its a composite value.
Or is there a way to represent lat and lang value as one single double value?

Would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

The FS endpoint and the JAVA FS API call dont have 1:1 argument mapping.
Argument 5 is a string and expects lat,lang arg 6 is a double expecting accuracy value.